# How to conditionally format cells to a certain color if they contain the value of "next hour" (current hour + 1)?

Tags: google-sheets, time, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting

Pretty much self-explanatory title. I have a scheduling sheet with cells representing when people have scheduled something.

It's organized by rows representing persons, columns representing days, and cells containing the hour value (ie 16, 17, 18, ...)

How can I conditionally format the cells so they are a certain color, let's say green, if the hour value is the next hour from "now". For example, if it's 20 o'clock (8pm) and cell value is '19'.

Comment: Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: @Rubén - There is none relevant. I tried to make a formula myself (incl. looking up formula stuffs); couldn't. Tried to look for one online; didn't find any. - Genuine case of "I know the answer is simple; I just don't have the basis to know what to look for", and making a long description of search efforts on a simple question defeats the purpose. It's like asking someone who has a simple newtonian physics problem to describe why the quantum physics stuff he found didn't solve it. Quantum physics was not involved; he (I) just didn't know where to look at.

Comment: your question already has the most important keywords "conditional format"; there are >1k results here https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-sheets%5D+conditional+format. Anyway, I'm glad that you already got an accepted an answer.

Comment: @Rubén I think you gravelly underestimate the scope of "conditional format". The problem was not "how to get into the conditional formatting menu?", it was a specific thing to be done with conditional formatting. ... While search results mix all kinds of stuff and none seem to point to anything useful on how to do this one specific thing. LOL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=A2>TIMEVALUE(NOW()+1)
```

[image]

---

### UPDATE:

```
=A2>(HOUR(NOW())+1)
```

Comment: `TIMEVALUE(...)` didn't work, as hours that have already elapsed were getting formatted too, but replacing with `(HOUR(NOW())+1)` did it. Thanks!